# JQuery selectable cell

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a problem with the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/54Dd9/

```
$('#dynamictable').append('<table id="selectable"></table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();    
table.append("<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>");
table.append("<tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>");

$("#selectable").selectable({
                filter: "td",
                selecting: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log($(ui.selecting).prevAll().length);   
                }
            });
```

I need to select the row and the columns.

Can you help me?

Comment: $(...).selectable is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that required to append table with script?
if its not then u can use this way,

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/54Dd9/1/`
```

you have to use jquery ui to use selectable function

`http://jsfiddle.net/54Dd9/3/`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#identifier').selectable({ });
```

is not part of the jquery core library,

You need to include the jQuery UI library which has this functionality 
http://jqueryui.com/

Updated your fiddle to a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/54Dd9/2/